# Scrapy - 403 error not solving even after adding Headers

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape `doordash.com`. But everytime I run the request it shows 403 and also this line `INFO: Ignoring response <403 http://doordash.com/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`.

I tried many things like adding User-Agent but still it didn't work. I also added full headers but again same thing is happening.
Here's my code:

```
class DoordashSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'doordash'
    allowed_domains = ['doordash.com']
    start_urls = ['http://doordash.com/']
    

    def start_requests(self):
        headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('Crawled Successfully')
```

How to get 200 ?

Comment: Did you try to reach the website on your browser? If you can't, probably the website banned your ip.

Comment: Website is reachable from my system. I read other similar questions and most probable cause is that ```cloudflare``` is hindering the request and catching the bot.